# Why doesn't the concat method affect the length property of an array?

Tags: javascript

i don't get why this won't work:

```
var test = ["String", 300];
var other = test.concat(500);
alert(test[2]);
```

or

```
alert(test.length) // 1 not 2
```

Is there a method that allows one to add an element to an existing array and make it accessible like above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) returns a *new* array. What you want is [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
test.push(500);
```

Demo to see the difference:

```
> var test = ["String", 300];
> var other = test.concat(500);
> test
[ 'String', 300 ]
> other
[ 'String', 300, 500 ]

> test.push(1234)
> test
[ 'String', 300, 1234 ]
> other
[ 'String', 300, 500 ]
```

Comment: thanks for the example and for the links ... 6 more minutes until I accept :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to add an element to this array, use **[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** -

```
var test = ["String", 300];
test.push(500);

alert(test[2]);  // will alert 500
alert(test.length); // will alert 3
```

It's much easier than `concat` if all you want to do is to add elements to an existing array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use different operators to add new elements to array, because JavaScript is a very flexible language.

You can use [push()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp):

```
var test = ["String", 300];
test.push(500);
```

Or add a new element at the next index of array:

```
var test = ["String", 300];
test[test.length] = 500;
```

Or use [concat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) like in your question:

```
var test = ["String", 300];
var other = test.concat(500);
    ^^^^^
```

In the last example the result concatenation is saved in the **other** variable (not **test**).

```
other == ["String", 300, 500]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `push` method like below to add elements to the existing array.

`test.push(500);`

**EDIT:** `concat()` returns a new array as already pointed out by ThiefMaster.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/VTcUH/)